# How do I get mail to trust my mail server?

Tags: pantheon-mail, security

I'm running Zimbra mail server on a Linux box. Thought I'd give Elementary a whirl to see if it's something my family members could use. When I ran Mail and gave it my account settings, I was prompted to trust the server (which has a self-signed certificate). After I did so, I got the message

Unable to store server trust exception
Couldn't find a place to store the pinned certificate

Not quite sure how to proceed here. Seems to me there are plenty of places to store a certificate :-)

Comment: I use Thunderbird a really long time. I have had exactly the same problem as you. I have my own mail server (postfix,dovecot,with spf, opendkim and opendmarc and of course certificate). Thunderbird does not have this issue. Actually you can remove the default mail app by typing in terminal: sudo apt purge pantheon-mail

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Gmail account, you gotta  active an option that makes you free to login in any external app from Gmail.

Just go to GMAIL Main page > Settings > Fowarding and POP/IMAP

Once you are here in Fowarding and POP/IMAP

> Enable IMAP

Hope that works your u, it work in my case.

Comment: Eh? I'm running my own mail server with my own domain - nothing to do with Gmail. Also, I'm trying the email application built into Elementary (a Linux distro) and trying to connect to my own mail server.

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment it was on your own domain. Rather than using a self signed certificate, I'd encourage you to use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) I'm using it for my own nextcloud, as well as a home developed webapp. They've got great tools and docs to help you set it up, and even auto refresh it at 90 day intervals.

What they give you is a FREE (as in beer, at least) signed ssl cert. That you may even use commercially.

Comment: Sure --- I have LetsEncrypt on other servers. But the issue here is that mail clients on various other OSs that I use have no problem accessing my mail server (Mac OSX, Windows, iOS, Thunderbird on Linux) and the issue is only happening with the mail client that comes with Elementary.

Comment: In that case I think you need to file a bug report on GitHub https://github.com/elementary/mail I do think it should give you a warning, but not prevent usage.